# Excel Conditional Formatting, based on difference of 2 cell calculation

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I've been trying to create a conditional formatting based on calculation of 2 cell.

The logic is, if the current month increases/decreases more than x or -x from previous month, then it will highlight or change or even better if I can use icon to show it.

So for example, for the month of march, since it decreases more than 2pts, than the cell should turn red.  And for the month of Feb, since it increases by 2pts, then the cell should turn green.

[image: sample sheet]

Is there any way to do this? and Copy Paste this through the table?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following formulas for conditional formatting starting in feb:

=(b2-a2)>2 set the format to fill in green
=(b2-a2)<2 set the format to fill in red

and then use format painter to copy that formatting for the other cells.